# Matter.js - simple board game

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am using **matter.js** to create a simple game where you have to push a ball into the hole.

[image]

If I use `isStatic: false` for ball object, it falls down when game is started. How can I rotate the whole platform so it is horizontal and objects don't fall down but can be pushed?

Comment: set gravity to `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the gravity;

```
engine.world.gravity.x = 0;
engine.world.gravity.y = 0;
```

<sup>[Docs](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/World.html#property_gravity)</sup>

---

Example;

```js
// Matter
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Render = Matter.Render,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

// Engine
var engine = Engine.create();

// Disable gravity
engine.world.gravity.y = 0; 
// engine.world.gravity.x = 0; (Not required in this case)

// Render
var render = Render.create({
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine
});

// Ball
var ball = Bodies.circle(300, 300, 150);

// Add ball
World.add(engine.world, [ ball ]);

// Run
Engine.run(engine);
Render.run(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.14.2/matter.min.js"></script>

<body>
```

Comment: `engine.world.gravity` should be `engine.gravity` in >= 0.17.0. See https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Engine.html#property_gravity